# Effect of request randomization before and after start_item() call

Tags: uvm, pipelining

I am trying to implement a UVM Driver for a simple pipelined model using semaphores, fork-join & get()-put() methods in the run_phase of the driver.

The driver part is doing the job fine if only I code the sequence in a particular way. From what I know the body task is coded as below

```
  Code1:
pkt = packet::type_id::create("pkt");    // Factory create the sequence item  
for(int i=0;i<num_trans;i++)             // Repeat as required
  begin
    assert(pkt.randomize());             // Randomize the sequence item
    start_item(pkt);                     //Send the request to Driver. 
    finish_item(pkt);                    //Wait for the driver to finish the current item
```

Above style, there's no pipelining achieved and moreover the data beat corresponding to the first transaction packet is lost. When the randomization is invoked after start_item, the test bench works as expected.

```
Code2:
pkt = packet::type_id::create("pkt");      
for(int i=0;i<num_trans;i++)
  begin
    
    start_item(pkt); 

     assert(pkt.randomize());       
    finish_item(pkt);
```

I'd like to know what is the difference between coding style 1 and 2

Comment: Just a minor comment, it's important to not put assert() around those randomize calls. There can be times when people turn off assertions during simulation. If they do that, all of a sudden your randomizations will not run and no one will know that the randomizations are disabled. Instead you should do an "if(!pkt.randomize()) uvm_error" or something equivalent

Answer (score 1):

This might be happening because on the task start_item() task we are waiting for the following.

```
sequencer.wait_for_grant(this, set_priority);
```

so we are waiting for the sequencer to grant the sequence and then sequence_item will be taken, but if you do like the following.

```
assert(pkt.randomize());  // Randomize the sequence item
start_item(pkt);          //Send the request to Driver.
```

that randomization lost because that start_item might be waiting for the sequencer to be free and till that time we lost the randomization.

further you can read the following article, that might help https://verificationacademy.com/forums/uvm/startitem/finishitem-versus-uvmdo-macros